# Makefile: "ld: can't link with a main executable file" in C

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to compile two c files, `calutil.c` and `calutil.h` into one executable. Here is my makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c11 -DNDEBUG

all: caltool

caltool: calutil.o caltool.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) calutil.o caltool.o

caltool.o: caltool.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) caltool.c -o caltool.o

calutil.o: calutil.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c calutil.c -o calutil.o
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.out
```

`calutil.c` has no `main`, while `caltool.c` has a `main.` I get the error

`ld: can't link with a main executable file` when I `make`. What is the cause of this?

Comment: Which version of `make` do you use? For what you want to achieve, your `Makefile` might be overly complicated, especially when you're using GNU make.

Comment: Hey, I use 3.81. Any simplifications would be awesome.

Comment: Second rule is missing `-c`, so `caltool.o` is a *complete program* not an object file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that some your recipe for linkage is missing the output file, and that your compilation is missing `-c`.

In case you're using GNU make, the following `Makefile` would be sufficient to do what you want to do:

```
CFLAGS:=-Wall -std=c11
CPPFLAGS:=-DNDEBUG

.PHONY: all
all: caltool

caltool: caltool.o calutil.o

.PHONY: clean
clean::
        $(RM) *.o
```

Explanation:

- When you're not using target-specific variables, you should use `:=` instead of `=` to assign variables so that they're expanded at assignment and not at evaluation.
- When your `Makefile` grows and you split it, you might want to have multiple targets called `clean` which all would be executed. In that case use `clean::` instead of `clean:`.
- There's a predefined variable to call `rm`, it is `$(RM)` and it includes the `-f` flag to prevent the `Makefile` from failing in case one or more of the files to be removed do not exist in the first place.
- The pattern for `clean` should be `*.[adios]` (that's really easy to remember, adios is Spanish for goodbye) so that it removes intermediate archives (`.a` when you build your own static libraries), dependency files (`.d`), preprocessor output (`.i`) and assembler files (`.s`) in case you use `-save-temps` to see what the compiler is doing.
- GNU make has built-in rules to compile and link, see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/default.c?id=3.81

  - The built-in rule for compilation calls `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $@ $<` so you don't need to write your own rule.
  - The built-in rule for linkage calls `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@`
- Targets which are not files themselves should be declared `.PHONY` to prevent confusion when a user creates a file with the same name, like `all` or `clean`.
- I do not see how any of your commands would create a file matching the glob pattern `*.out`, so I removed that part of the `clean` rule.
- Flags for the preprocessor should go into `CPPFLAGS` instead of `CFLAGS`. Preprocessor flags typically are all those `-D` and `-I` flags and would also be passed to other tools that use a C preprocessor in the same project, like `splint` or `PC-Lint`.

When the `Makefile` is run, it is looking how to make `all`, and it finds that for `all` it has to make `caltool`. For `caltool` it finds that it has to first make `calutil.o` and `caltool.o`. When it tries to make `calutil.o` and `caltool.o`, it finds that it can make them from `calutil.c` and `caltool.c` and will do so. Then it will link `caltool.o` and `calutil.o` into `caltool`.

From your naming I guessed that it's `caltool.c` that contains the `main()` function. It is helpful to place the object which contains `main()` first once you use static link libraries.

Edit: Here's some more magic for you. I assume that you have a header file `calutil.h` which is included by `caltool.c` to access extern symbols provided by `calutil.c`. You want to rebuild all objects that depend on these header files. In this case, add the following lines to your Makefile:

```
CPPFLAGS+=-MMD
-include caltool.d calutil.d
```

In order to not have the list of objects multiple times, you could add a variable `objects` like this:

```
objects:=caltool.o calutil.o
```

You would then build the application with this rule:

```
caltool: $(objects)
```

And include the dependency files like this:

```
-include $(objects:.o=.d)
```

In case you keep your working tree "clean", i.e. do not "pollute" it with "alien" code, i.e. you always want to include all `.c` files in your project, you can change the definition of `objects` as follows:

```
sources:=$(wildcard *.c)
objects:=$(sources:.c=.o)
```

In case you wonder why it is `CPPFLAGS` (uppercase) but `objects` (lowercase): it is common to use uppercase for all variables which configure the recipes of rules and control the built-in behavior of `make`, tools built on top of it, and classic environment variables, and lowercase variables for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the .o files from the directory, and edited my makefile to add `-c` to the `caltool.o` line.